# Check if given string represents a primitive type

Tags: java

I have a method that accepts a string and tries to cast it to a class using `Class.forName()`. I want to check before I call this method that if the string represents a primitive type. Is there any way to do this other than running 8 `String.equals` calls? Code:

```
public String myMethod(String returnType) {
    if(checkPrimitive(returnType))
        return returnType;
    String typeArgs = Arrays.stream(Class.forName(returnType).getTypeParameters())
                    .map(typeVar -> typeVar.getBounds()[0].getTypeName())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The most natural way to do this is to use `Class#isPrimitive`. But to do that you first have to get the class object. Is that really a problem?

Comment: Guava has a method that promises to _"return an immutable set of all nine primitive types (including void)"_. Perhaps use that? https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/24.0-jre/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#allPrimitiveTypes--

Comment: @Lii if I try to get the class object for primitive types using Class.forName, it gives a ClassNameNotFoundException which I want to use to handle cases where the classes that really do not exist.

Comment: @Henrik I think that won't help as I have a String and that returns a Set<Class<?>>

Comment: as you got exception, is it not possible to try/catch it in checkPrimitive method? This is not very beautiful, but it should work

Comment: @Pavlo that'd require two calls to Class.forName which I think would have worse impact in a project with 100s of classes than just string compares.

Comment: Actually if would you pass to your myMethod variable reference instead of string you would be able to call any Object method and if it fails it will mean null or primitive

Comment: Why two calls? Just create variable before you fire first call and then use it later if there was no exception fired at validation

Comment: If would your myMethod parameter type was an Object (not String with name), then you would not get primitives there  at all.

Comment: @Pavlo I don't have the object I want to work with. I need this for jackson deserialization to get the type parameters of a class by its classname. That thing about a single call makes sense.

Comment: Well Jackson ... then you looks like invent something already exist. Why you cannot use Jackson mapping to custom model object?

Comment: Its actually existing infra I'm working on and the way things work right now in it requires doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `ClassUtils.getClass(returnType);` from apache-commons.
This considers primitives as well and will you give you a class object. You can then call `isPrimitive()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all class objects for the primitive type with the Guava method [`allPrimitiveTypes`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#allPrimitiveTypes()) and then check the name of those:

```
Set<String> names = Primitives.allPrimitiveTypes().stream().map(Class::getName).collect(toSet());
if (names.contains(returnType)) {
    ...
}
```